# Why does this code cause a Segmentation Fault?

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

I'm writing a function that returns the first `n` (`n <= strlen(src)`) characters of a string.

```
char* substring(char *src, int n)
{
   char *substr;
   int i;
   for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
     *substr++ = *src++;
   src = src - n;
   *substr = '\0';
   return substr - n;
}
```

This function returns the right answer when called only once but returns a Seg Fault when it is called more than once.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No memory is allocated for `substr` and the function therefore deferences an uninitialized pointer and is writing to memory where it is not supposed to resulting in **undefined behaviour**. The fact it works the first time is complete chance.

Allocate memory for `substr`:

```
char* substr = malloc(n + 1); /* Plus one for null teminator. */
```

Note that the caller of `substring()` must `free()` the returned buffer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to allocate memory for the char *substr in your substring function. You're clobbering memory at the moment which is causing the segfaults. A simple:
    char *substr = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char)*n+1);
should do the trick.